# Restore session/state in terminals

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, ubuntu-12.04, tmux

When I close my browser it remembers "state" in the sense that it remembers what tabs I have open and text that I had entered into various forms.

**Is there a way to do something similar with my terminal sessions?**

I would happily spend quite a bit of processor time to guarantee that if my box suddenly shuts off, I can boot up to the same suite of `tmux`, `man` pages, `R` sessions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not a fine grained control as the ideal solution would be, maybe this will help:
[Restore tmux session after reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/440015/restore-tmux-session-after-reboot)

Comment: Ah, yeah - I've tried this before and it was my dissatisfaction with that solution that led me to pose the question. =)    Thanks though.