# Save and restore terminal on reboot in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-20.04, session-restore, terminator

The answer is present for previous Ubuntu LTS versions [here](https://superuser.com/a/995244/860962) but this does not work for Ubuntu 20.04 since 20.04 LTS does not have the option to `Create new` and then `Link to application` from the desktop. One way to have a shortcut to launch an application from the desktop is to use Nautilus with the command `nautilus /usr/share/applications/` , but I have not been able to fix it in such a way that it follows the last steps of the answer given in the link above. How have you fixed this problem?